# Counting Number of even and distinct digits

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The Question was: The number of even four-digit decimal numbers with no digit repeated.

So the first digit cannot be 0 so there are 9 ways to choose a digit. Then for the 3rd, 2nd and 1st digits there would be respectively 9 ways (adding back the zero as an option), 8 ways, 7 ways. So then the total possibilities are 4,536 but then since we are looking for even numbers we divide this number by 2 and we get 2,268. I don't understand why this is wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Was your question solved ?

Answer (score 3):

The number of *even* four-digit decimal numbers with no digit repeated is not equal to the number of *odd* four-digit decimal numbers with no digit repeated.  So it's not as straightforward as diving by $2$.

I suggest you try starting with the possible values $x\ \_\ \_\ y$, since once $x$ and $y$ are determined, we can always fill in the other cells in $8 \times 7$ ways.  You'll also see why the numbers above are different (there's more pairs $(x,y)$ for which $y$ is even then for which $y$ is odd).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Rebecca, the number of numbers (even and odd) are not same...
My approach: four digit numbers ending with 0,2,4,6,8 with no digits repeated.

> Case #base
>   1. ending with 0 : _ _ _ 0 = 9*8*7*1 = 504
>       leftmost digit can be in {1,2,...9} and without repetition, each time one number is removed.
>   
>    Case #other
>     as the number can start with any digit, except 0...
>
> 2. ending with 2 : _ _ _ 2 = 8*8*7*1 = 448
> 3. ending with 4 : _ _ _ 4 = 8*8*7*1 = 448
> 4. ending with 6 : _ _ _ 6 = 8*8*7*1 = 448
> 5. ending with 8 : _ _ _ 8 = 8*8*7*1 = 448

And the answer is $504+(4*448)$ =  2296
thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

$4 \cdot 9  \cdot 8  \cdot 7=2016$

Since the last digti you have only $\ 2,\ 4,\ 6,\ 8\ $ four numbers to choose.

Comment: Incorrect, as the leftmost digit can't be 0.